# Render function only once in React

Tags: reactjs

I need to run a random number generator only once (and never re render), I'm trying to use useCallback but I must be doing something wrong since it's not returning any value.

```
function Editor() {

    function genRandom() {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0) + 0);
    return random;
    }


    const randomNum = useCallback(() => {
        genRandom();
    }, []);


    console.log(randomNum);
}

export default Editor;
```

randomNum is not returning anything at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

This is because `randomNum` is a function. `useCallback` returns a memoized ***function***, so it still needs to be invoked.

```
function Editor() {

  function genRandom() {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0) + 0);
    return random;
  }

  const randomNum = useCallback(() => {
    genRandom();
  }, []);

  console.log(randomNum); // <-- not invoked
}
```

The `randomNum` function is a stable reference to the following function definition:

```
() => {
  genRandom();
}
```

## Solution

You should use `useMemo` instead of `useCallback` to get a memoized random value. Remember to return the generated value. I don't see any component dependencies in `getRandom` so you should also factor that *outside* the component so it isn't being redefined each render cycle.

```
function genRandom() {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0) + 0);
  return random;
}

function Editor() {
  ...

  const randomNum = useMemo(
    () => genRandom(),
    [/* dependency to trigger computing new random value */]
  );

  ...
  console.log(randomNum);
  ...
}

export default Editor;
```

[image: Edit sweet-heisenberg-2uf9j]

If you are trying to declare `genRandom` *inside* a React component and want to provide a stable callback handler to be called later then use the `useCallback` hook and keep in mind that it's returning a memoized function instead of a value, so the function would still need to be invoked.

```
function Editor() {
  ...

  function genRandom() {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0) + 0);
    return random;
  }

  const randomNum = useCallback(
    () => genRandom(),
    [] // <-- empty dependency array
  );

  ...
  console.log(randomNum()); // <-- invoke to get random number
  ...
}
```

[image: Edit render-function-only-once-in-react (forked)]

Comment: Using this same method, how can I update it onclick? I created a function but it seems it's not re-writing the value for randomNum

Comment: @Esteban89 In this case I'd just put it in state. `const [randomNum, setRandomNum] = useState(genRandom());` and use the state update function as a callback `onClick={() => setRandomNum(genRandom())}`. If necessary you can factor out the anonymous callback, `const setRandomNumCB = () => setRandomNum(genRandom());` then `onClick={setRandomNumCB}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hook:

```
function useRandomValueOnce() {
  // or return React.useMemo(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0) + 0), []);
  return React.useRef(Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0) + 0)).current;
}

const randomNumber = useRandomValueOnce();
```

`useCallback` is meant to return a function that is created once, but when you call it, it will always run. To make it return a value, you need a return statement.

`useRef` keep a reference for a mutable value, and only get updated if you instruct it to do so.

same for `useMemo` that only a dependency changes.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-fire-bdopw) that uses the preceding hook.

Even if you hit the rerender button, the value stays the same.

You can make the value change by using useMemo inside the hook and making it accept parameters that are dependencies to recalculate it.

PS: You must not use the hook; you can easily port this line of code to any of your components:

```
const randomValue = React.useMemo(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0) + 0), [])
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed

Comment: This solution runs random generator every time. It just ignores the new values.

Answer (score 0):

Just to fix the bug that is actually present in your code. It isn't returning anything because you aren't returning anything inside the useCallback function argument.

You need to write it like this. Notice the `return getRandom();`

```
    const randomNum = useCallback(() => {
        return genRandom();
    }, []);
```

The way your code is, it is returing undefined because any function which doesn't return anything returns undef. So that's the bug in your actual code which is why it's not being set. Otherwise I think using `useCallback` is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this.

The shortest is with a [lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state):

```
function Editor() {
    const [randomNum] = useState(() =>
        Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0) + 0)
    );
    console.log(randomNum); 
}
```

`useRef` will return the same number on each render. But it will also calculate a new random number and throw it away on every render.

`useMemo`, `useCallback` and `useEffect(() => {...}, [])` require some extra coding and might consume extra resources.

Comment: I would against advice using useState, because it is a one time solution and does not provide extensibility. I bet we'll later need dependencies to get a new number. In this case, either ref with an if/else or useMemo is the way to go. And i don't see how useEffect would solve this without a re-render since it is executed after the paint.

Comment: `useEffect` or `useLayoutEffect` are not the best options here. But they are still better than `useRef` since they don't call `Math.random` every time. For later `const [randomNum, setRandomNum] = useState(...)` may be better than `useMemo`, may be not. It depends :)